# $f: \Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z \to\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ such that $f(m,n) = (2m+3n, 3n+2n)$, $π : \Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ such that $π(m,n) = m$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to prove that $π \circ f $ is onto but not injective. 
I don't ask for a solution, I ask for some hint?

Comment: Hint (for both questions): solve the equation $2x+3y=1$.

Comment: How far have you got? Do you have an explicit expression for $\pi\circ f$?

Comment: I solved the equation. I can't understand what to do further.:/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to establish that $(\pi\circ f)(m,n)=2m+3n$ as a map $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is (1) onto, and (2) not injective.

Note that $(\pi\circ f)(2k,-k)=k$. so $\pi\circ f$ is onto.

Note that $(\pi\circ f)(0,0)=(\pi\circ f)(-3,2)=0$, so $\pi\circ f$ is not one-one.

Comment: Thank you so much!